# Objective-C condition waiting

Tags: objective-c, concurrency, block, conditional-statements, grand-central-dispatch

I'm executing two asynchronous methods, both answering through blocks. I have to wait for both blocks to be called before I call a third one. Using dispatch_group would work if my methods were synchronous, but I don't want to change them, since it would require lots of code refactoring.

Better explaining the problem:

```
[myLib doTask1:^{
     // do stuff when task1 is done
}];

[myLib doTask2:^{
     // do stuff when task2 is done
}];
```

And then I'd like to do something like:

```
[self executeThisWhenBothTasksDone:^{
    // do stuff after both tasks are done
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dispatch_group_enter` and `dispatch_group_leave` would help you. The least code change might be this.

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_enter(group);
[myLib doTask1:^{
     // do stuff when task1 is done
     dispatch_group_leave(group);
}];

dispatch_group_enter(group);
[myLib doTask2:^{
     // do stuff when task2 is done
     dispatch_group_leave(group);
}];

dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self executeThisWhenBothTasksDone:^{
        // do stuff after both tasks are done
    }
});
```

Comment: I recommend you to create a question instead of under the comments

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dispatch_group_async` and `dispatch_group_notify` to get this behavior for non-synchronous methods